# ECMAScript 6 modules in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Node.JS v0.11.3 claims to have support for ECMAScript 6 modules with the flag `--harmony_modules`.

I have tried various examples, such as the following.

```
module math {
    export var pi = 3.141593;
}
```

What is the syntax to get modules working in Node.JS?

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: It works the second time only :-/

Comment: [Seems like Chrome doesn't support modules yet](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Modules). Based on this, can we say that V8 in general doesn't support it then?

Comment: Looks like NodeJS is looking into it: [git#5](https://github.com/nodejs/NG/issues/5)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The modules implementation in V8 is incomplete. There's parsing support when enabled with --harmony-modules, but support of the actual functionality was put on hold. The reason for this is because the specification for how ES6 modules will actually work has been in the works and is still not fully nailed down.

The implementation in Continuum (the linked screenshot from Crazy Train's answer) dates back to an interim spec from November 2012 and is now woefully out of date because of the ongoing changes to the ES6 module's spec. This is why the V8 devs put development of support for modules on hold.

It seems like the modules spec is approaching stability (though I expect we'll see small refinements for a while) and I think (hope at least) that we'll see SpiderMonkey and V8 moving forward with implementations over the next 6 months.

Useful links:

- V8 modules bug: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569
- SpiderMonkey modules bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=harmony%3Amodules

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Continuum](http://benvie.github.io/continuum/), which is an ES6 virtual machine written in (current) JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: @Randomblue: The example is in your question. It sounds to me like you're looking for a test environment.

Comment: I'm actually looking for an example specifically working on V8.

Comment: @Randomblue: Sounds to me like V8 doesn't support the most recent semantics of the ECMAScript 6 modules. In other words, as it stands, you can't run ECMAScript modules in V8 since they have some non-compliant implementation.

Comment: Do you have any idea *what* this "non-compliant" implementation looks like?