# Node 6 compliance with ES6 specification about strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The ES6 specification says that all modules are run in strict mode. But according to my tests it seems that this is not the case. Is node 6 ES6 compliant about strictness or am I doing something wrong on my side ?

Thank you

Comment: Real, native ES6 modules are not implemented in Node.JS just yet (or rather V8, JavaScript engine that it's using).

Comment: Ok, I thought node6 was compliant now. If it is not the case then I will have to update my linter. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330078/ecmascript-6-modules-in-node-js?

Comment: http://node.green (doesn't list modules though because they are not supported at all yet).

Comment: node.green should at least mention modules in red.